# How can I print specific items from a list without using a loop

Tags: python-3.x, printing, items

I want to be able to somehow print several specific items without using a loop

```py
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

print(my_list[0,5,7])
```

I got this error:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: You need a loop to specify the items, otherwise how does the interpreter knows which elements to choose?

Comment: But the items are specified? It doesn't allow me to have more than 1 argument but something like:   my_list[0:5]  works

Comment: Thats structure is list slicing where you specify a range of indexes to print, I suggest you to look it up.if you want disjointed indexes , like 1st 4th 7th index you need to specify them explicitly

Comment: Would you mind sending me a link about this topic because I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for. Thanks. I'm trying to make a TicTacToe game, and at this stage, I'm making a function that looks at the 0, 3 and 6 place(vertical) to see if its an "X" or "O". It's in a for loop so when it's done checking those it checks the 0+1, 3+1, 6+1 pos etc.but that doesn't work and I don't want to make the code super long and ugly.

Comment: Sure, perhaps look here! https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension-and-slicing/

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
l=np.array(my_list)
l[[0,5,7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not allow you to do things like `list[1, 2, 3]` to get elements 1, 2, and 3 from a list. Instead, you must get each element individually, like so:

`print(list[1], list[2], list[3])`